# Extract multiple files in folder - [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, zip

I'm running the following script to unzip several zipfiles from a directory:

```
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile

dir_name = f"C:/my_path/zip/{name}"

def main():

    for item in os.listdir(dir_name):
        with ZipFile(item, 'r') as zipObj: 
            listOfFileNames = zipObj.namelist()
            for fileName in listOfFileNames: 
                if fileName.endswith('.csv'):
                    for i in fileName:
                        zipObj.extract(fileName, f"C:/my_path/csv/{name}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The point is that I've confirmed a hundred times that the zip files are stored in the right path but I can't run the script but I did succesfully in another computer (?)

What I am doing wrong?

#### EDIT:

This is the entire error message:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-7f26de4464fe> in <module>
     18 
     19 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 20     main()

<ipython-input-6-7f26de4464fe> in main()
     10 
     11     for item in os.listdir(dir_name): # Iterate over the zip file
---> 12         with ZipFile(item, 'r') as zipObj: # Create a ZipFile Object and load sample.zip in it
     13             listOfFileNames = zipObj.namelist() # Get a list of all archived file names from the zip
     14             for fileName in listOfFileNames: # Iterate over the file names

C:\Anaconda\lib\zipfile.py in __init__(self, file, mode, compression, allowZip64)
   1111             while True:
   1112                 try:
-> 1113                     self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
   1114                 except OSError:
   1115                     if filemode in modeDict:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'my_file.zip'
```

Comment: you shouldn't hard-code paths, see [no-such-file-or-directory-with-absolute-path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58383714/no-such-file-or-directory-with-absolute-path/58383966#58383966)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['No such file or directory' with absolute Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58383714/no-such-file-or-directory-with-absolute-path)

Comment: I don't see a variable named `name`.  However, you're referencing it in your f-strings.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the key:

Revise this line:

```
dir_name = f"C:/my_path/zip/{name}"
```

To:

```
dir_name = "C:/my_path/zip"
```

Why?
Because `os.listdir` is looking in a directory named `"C:/my_path/zip/{name}"` but it doesn't exist as the variable `name` has not been declared.  Thus the error below, as triggered on my machine (albeit Linux, hence the non-Windows type path):

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/devmt/services/{name}'
```

Then, apply this logic throughout the rest of your function and perhaps use `os.path.join` to stitch your path and filenames together.

Comment: Indeed, the variable `name` is inherited from another part of thecode where I made a scraping to dowload the zip files.