# How to select a specific directory to copy from its source to new destination using Python?

Tags: python, rename, shutil

I have a script that  copy folder and files from their source to a new destination,  the script works as it should using `shutil` module. But I am hard coding the source for folders.

What I need is to make the script select the desired folder  where it has a specific name. as
**pdf 11-12-02-2020** so it pdf + date yesterday - current date - current month - current year.

how can I do this ?

code:

```
import os
import shutil
from os import path
import datetime

src = "I:\\"
src2 = "I:/pdf 11-12-02-2020"

dst = "C:/Users/LT GM/Desktop/pdf 11-12-02-2020/"


def main():
    copy()

def copy():
    if os.path.exists(dst): 
        shutil.rmtree(dst)
        print("the deleted folder is :{0}".format(dst))
        #copy the folder as it is (folder with the files)
        copieddst = shutil.copytree(src2,dst)
        print("copy of the folder is done :{0}".format(copieddst))
    else:
        #copy the folder as it is (folder with the files)
        copieddst = shutil.copytree(src2,dst)
        print("copy of the folder is done :{0}".format(copieddst))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: as a side note, I would avoid having spaces in folder/file names in general. some libraries don't handle spaces well(i.e os library).If you need to then using dst=r'string' instead might be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3.6/library/datetime.html) module.

Additionally, you may want to use the `os` module to resolve the path correctly for you, see [this](https://docs.python.org/fr/3.6/library/os.path.html?highlight=os%20path%20join#os.path.join), since the `src` variable seems unused, it's better to remove it, with all that in mind:

```py
import calendar
import os
import shutil
from datetime import date
from os import path

def yesterday():
    day = int(date.today().strftime("%d"))
    month = int(date.today().strftime("%m"))
    year = int(date.today().strftime("%Y"))
    if day != 1:
        return day - 1
    long_months = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12]
    if month in long_months:
        return 31
    elif month == 2:
        if calendar.isleap(year):
            return 29
        return 28
    else:
        return 30

name = "pdf " + str(yesterday()) + date.today().strftime("-%d-%m-%Y")

src2 = os.path.join("I:/", name)

dst = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop",name)
```

As a side note, while in this case
`dst = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop" ,name)` 
 works, it's actually not advised to use it, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58383966/8873120)

Comment: what if i have more than 1 folder like **pdf 11-12-02-2020** & **pdf 10-11-02-2020** & **pdf 9-10-02-2020**     how can i copy all these folders?