# Remove file in python with absolute path: error "no such file or directory" but file exists

Tags: python

I'm trying to remove a file in Python 3 on Linux (RHEL) the following way:

```
os.remove(or.getcwd() + '/file.txt')
```

(sorry not allowed to publish the real paths).

and it gives me the usual error

```
No such file or directory: '/path/to/file/file.txt'
```

(I've respected slash or antislash in the path)

What is strange is that when I just `ls` the file (by copy pasting, so the very same path) the file does exist.

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58383714/no-such-file-or-directory-with-absolute-path) but i'm not on Windows and slash direction seems correct.

Any idea ?

EDIT: as suggested by @DominicPrice `os.system('ls')` is showing the file while `os.listdir()` does not show it (but shows other files in the same directory)

EDIT 2: So my issue was due a a bad usage of `os.popen`. I used this method to copy file but did not wait for the subprocess to be terminated. So my understanding is that the file was not copied yet when I tried to delete it.

Comment: If you run `os.listdir()`, does the file show up?

Comment: You have to either provide the absolute path of the `file.txt` or ensure the script runs in the same directory as where that file is

Comment: FYI pythons pathlib module makes working with paths much easier.

Comment: Can you confirm that the file path emitted in the error text is an absolute path?

Comment: @DominicPrice indeed the file does not appear in `os.listdir()`. Actually several files that are in the directory (checked through the linux shell) do not appear neither. I thought it might be a problem of permissions but all files have the same owener and at least have read permission

Comment: @DarkKnight yes it is the absolute path

Comment: Perhaps your code changed the current working directory - if so that's a bad habit which can cause all sorts of confusion like this, much better to leave current working directory unchanged.

Comment: yes but the path is displayed in the error message and I check that this path exists

Comment: (you're right my script changes the current dir)

Comment: How about if you run `os.system("ls")`, does it show up then? Maybe try run python with `sudo` anyway just to double check if that helps? But I'm afraid I don't think I know enough about how RHEL works to really help you, sorry.

Comment: @DominicPrice interesting `os.system('ls'))` is indeed showing the file

Comment: It might be done to the way I copy files in the current directory. I do it using `os.popen('cp ...')` but it this create a process there might be a synchro issue ?

Comment: I replaced the copy `os.popen('cp...')` by `os.system('cp...')` and the problem disappear (file appears in os.listdir and is removed properly)

Comment: Ok I think I see the problem, gimme a few clock cycles and I'll put an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, as you have explained in the comments, you are creating the file using `os.popen("cp ...")`. This works asynchronously, so it may not have had time to complete by the time you call `os.remove()`. You can force python to wait for it to finish by calling the `close` method:

```
proc = os.popen("cp myfile myotherfile")
proc.close() # wait for process to finish
os.remove("myotherfile") # we're all good
```

I would highly recommend staying away from using `os.popen` in favour of the `subprocess` library, which has a `run` function which is way safer to use.

For the specific functions of copying a file, an even better (and cross platform) solution is to use the [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) library:

```
import shutil
shutil.copyfile("myfile", "myotherfile")
```

Comment: Yes exactly. Using os.system is equivalent to os.popen + wait for process to finish

Answer (score -2):

you should use `os.path.dirname(__file__)`.
this is an inbuilt function of os module in python.
you can read more here.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-path-to-the-given-file-using-python/

Comment: This may or may not be what OP wants. This will return the containing folder for the script, which may be different from the current working directory. Point being, you're answering a different question than the one in the original post, so you may want to clarify that for completeness. This seems more like it should've been a comment, though.

Comment: don't understand how it solves anything. I know the path of the file, it is the current directory