# Is there a way to reference a username in a path when you dont know what username is on the system?

Tags: python, windows, file, path

I'm doing a school project that requires me to write a virus, I wanted to make a virus that deletes files on a system, but when using

```
os.remove()
```

it requires me to already have a path, does anyone know how to get around this?

I've already tried

```
path = (r"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop")
```

but that doesn't help and just leads to a Windows can't find path specified problem

Comment: Does [this](https://superuser.com/a/217506/76318) help? `%UserProfile%\Desktop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/getpass.html):

```
import getpass
curuser = getpass.getuser()
# Current User name
path = "C:\Users\%s\..." % curuser
```

Comment: Special folders such as "Desktop" are easily relocatable by the user. For ways to get the current location using PyWin32 and ctypes, see my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46391031/205580) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33181421/205580).